# How can I get a model I made to look I want it to in Unity 3D?

Tags: rendering, materials, unity

After I made a model of a cup

[image: my cup],

I did some work with materials, which when rendered looked this

[image].

When I saved my model and opened it in Unity3d, it was nothing like this [image]. What should I do for such result in unity3d?

Comment: Please edit your question and add an image showing the result in Unity.

Comment: I agree with cegaton, but in addition, I would suggest uploading a copy of your ~.blend file using [Blend exhange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or another online host, and editing a link into your post.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=321" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/321/)
 that is the model.
p.s. i know that my knowledge of english is low, so sorry, guys

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly how you want your cup to appear when imported into Unity 3D? What is wrong with the view you posted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Unity, not Blender.

Answer (score 2):

The last images show perspective distortion when you toggle the camera from 3d to 2d your model looks like:

[image]

You cup is almost 2m in reality this is how such a big cup appears with the given camera settings.

You receive poor topology from adding a subsurf modifier followd by a decimate modifier.